# OS services and Android OS using data

Tags: data-monitoring, operating-system, services, mobile-data

I have a question following up [Locking applications to wifi only data connections](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45147/locking-applications-to-wifi-only-data-connections):

I followed the guide given in [its answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/45151/16575) and notice some applications (like Android OS) don't have the option to be turned off. Is there any solution for this? At Data Usage the "app" called Android OS is using data but I don't wanna use data unless I'm on WiFi for that process.

What I'm trying to achieve (on the *Xperia Z*) is that on WiFi all apps have full access to the internet. On mobile data I only want Whatsapp and Gmail to be syncronised.

I disabled everything that uses data exept the mentioned apps above and I can't get

I also have [My Data Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/my-data-manager-data-usage/com.mobidia.android.mdm) installed. It says *OS services* is using 111kb so far, and it's going up. Another process called *Android System* has used 78kb.

In short again the question: some applications (like Android OS) don't have the option to be turned off in Data Usage. Is there a way to stop this process (and other processes) to use data unless I'm on WiFi?

Comment: I've just edited your question to make it easier to follow. Please check whether I got things right (especially the links I've added). // As for the question itself: I know of no way to restrict those system processes (covering behind "Android OS"). If you can identify them directly, and they use their own "Unix-ID", it should be possible via the Firewall part in the linked answer.

Comment: You're talking about cutting off the system itself from the internet while connected mobile, which is probably *not* a good idea. This includes the processes that **set up** your connection, receive Google push notifications (including GMail!), and so on. Probably, resolving DNS names is also affected. If you have *root access*, you can use iptables frontends (e.g. [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)) to set up a firewall and block certain apps, including the system and see how it affects the connectivity.

Comment: The OS services shouldn't need to be constantly connected especially when it uses a butt load of data. I just noticed today that the Android OS used about 1/3 of my data allowance for no apparent reason. I've since decided that when I'm not actively using data I turn it off.